# Feature to download partial file from GCS

Tags: c++, google-cloud-storage

Following code works pretty well with latest version of GCS. I can use it to download the complete file in one go.

```
gcs::ObjectReadStream stream = client.ReadObject(bucket_name, object_name);
```

But If my file is too long, I need to download it in segments. Can someone suggest how to read in smaller chunks? In another words how can I specify  range requests.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [API documentation for ReadObject](https://googleapis.dev/cpp/google-cloud-storage/latest/classgoogle_1_1cloud_1_1storage_1_1v1_1_1Client.html#a80bbd702b90dd38287b9bf1248272dbe):

```
auto stream = client.ReadObject(bucket_name, object_name, ReadRange(0, 100));
```

gets you the first 100 bytes.

Comment: The documentation link is to an old version of the library.